# Mysql previous date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I am using the following to have previous date data at 00.00.00

```
select * from perf where timeStamp="SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)";
```

But this is not resulting any output

where as

```
select * from perf where timeStamp="2014-11-28";
```

resulting the proper output

Can anyone of you please help me in trying to find out the issue.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use `timeStamp = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)`

Answer (score 3):

Check [**SUBDATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) function

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM perf
WHERE DATE(timeStamp) = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st no need to quote on `SUBDATE()` function and, you need to subtract 1 day

```
select * from perf where timeStamp=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1);
```

//or with details of input interval like `HOURS`, 'DAY', 'MONTH' etc

```
select * from perf where timeStamp=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timeStamp="SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)";
```

Searches for the string "SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)" and subdate is wrong executed

remove the " " and it should work like the following:

```
select * from perf where timeStamp= SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```